# How do I integrate this SQL query into other calculations in one script?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So I have written the following query:

```
SELECT 
Store,
Revenue

  FROM [mydb].[dbo].[orders] as orders

  WHERE 
  order_date BETWEEN '2015-10-26' AND '2015-11-22'
  AND 
  type_desc = 'north'


  AND store_number

  NOT IN(
  SELECT DISTINCT store_number
  FROM [mydb].[dbo].[orders] 
  WHERE 
  order_date BETWEEN '2015-10-26' AND '2015-11-22'
  AND 
  type_desc = 'south')

  GROUP BY 
  Store,
  Revenue
```

The aim of this query is to find revenue where the store appears in the north but not in the south. The query below works perfectly but what I would like to know is how I can make a more succinct version of this query so that I can integrate other things into it. I suppose I almost want to join other columns onto it which calculate things. So I would have multiple columns within my end result such as last year revenue for all store, this year revenue all stores, revenue for north and south ETC...

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation to categorize the stores by north and south revenue:

```
SELECT store,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'north' THEN Revenue ELSE 0 END) as north_revenue,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'south' THEN Revenue ELSE 0 END) as south_revenue
FROM [mydb].[dbo].[orders] o
WHERE o.order_date BETWEEN '2015-10-26' AND '2015-11-22'
GROUP BY store;
```

This would appear to be the base information that you want.

If you only want stores with north revenue and no south revenue, you can add:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'south' THEN Revenue ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

(Note:  If `Revenue` can be negative, then you might want to just count the values using `THEN 1` rather than `THEN Revenue`.)

Comment: Say I wanted to find revenue where there was a store in North AND South then SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'south' AND type_desc = 'north' THEN Revenue ELSE 0 END) = 0 won't work as there is only ever one type desc per store but multiple rows of stores so it would return 0 everytime... how would I find that out?

Comment: @AEJBUG . . . How about `sum(revenue)` for all stores?